# Noun for someone fun and caring and compassionate

Tags: nouns, vocabulary, epithet-requests

What is a noun for a person who is nice and caring and fun to be around (a noun to refer to the person, as in "Bob is a ***_*__*_*_**".

Comment: Not a noun, but I think one would typically use 'charismatic person'.

Comment: "friend": Bob is a friend. Or he should be.

Comment: Can't say about a single noun, but I'd say in that case "Bob is a hell of a guy".

Answer (score 6):

Although mensch is good, the person being called that will probably need a dictionary or they might punch you.  I prefer a more common word, **gentleman**.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! :)

Comment: @Peteris - I'm quite illiterate, but I read a lot.

Comment: While John Henry Newman might agree with you ("It is almost a definition of a gentleman to say that he is one who never inflicts pain"), Oscar Wilde might demur ("A gentleman is one who never hurts anyone's feelings **unintentionally**").

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a **[delight](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/delight_1)**

> great pleasure, satisfaction, or happiness, or something or someone that gives this

Another possibility is **[charmer](http://www.yourdictionary.com/charmer)**

> a person who is enchanting or delightful to be around

However, this latter term is sometimes used to signify one who is engaging but insincere.

Comment: Sounds like a fancy man to me!

Comment: Makes me want to combine the answers as "delightful gentleman" or "charmer gentleman". But that wouldn't really work out, would it? :)

Comment: @Nav What about those *nice and caring and fun to be around* women?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a Yiddish loan word:  **mensch** comes to mind.

It means he's an honorable, good person, but it's taken on all sorts of other positive connotations since its importation to English.

It doesn't quite bring up the fun to be around part, though.

Used in the example sentence:  Bob is a **real mensch**.

Otherwise, you would just call him a **great guy**.  Which probably brings with it all of the connotations you were trying to express.

Comment: Beat me to it! Since I've searched extensively for literally _years_, I know that this is likely the best answer. I also use polyanna occasionally, with the understanding it's awkward when referring to males and that neither is common enough to be used safely in all contexts.

Comment: @jboneca I have the distinct advantage of being Jewish and having grown up with this word in common parlance.  :-)

Comment: I don't think I could ever get away calling any of my friends a real mensch... which would probably translate to them... real munch... to... real muncher... to ass muncher.

Comment: @RyeBread Well, you have several options: get new friends, educate your friends, move to an area with a larger Jewish population, etc.  Besides, with a name like RyeBread ... I would have thought ... well, that you are tribe.  No?

Comment: Well I wasn't counting my Jewish friends... but the others... educate them?  Then they would be no fun.

Comment: As a Jew myself, I'm not averse to using it _among people I know will understand_. But it gets tiresome answer, "wait, what does that mean?" for those who aren't of the Hebraic persuasion.

Comment: @jboneca  I can see that. But, the meaning is fairly well known in the Northeast and anywhere that Jews tend to be plentiful.

Answer (score 1):

How about **social butterfly** or **philantropist**?
(And one which could be used in a more colloquial context or as a nickname, which I just came up with is **jokebox**. Only half-serious suggestion... ;) )

Comment: Philanthropists are not necessarily fun. They can be quite serious, some of them!

Comment: Although I am being quite a hypocrit with that demand (since I didn't use any), but what are your sources? Who are you referring to? In my understanding, a philantropist is, profanely put, a lover of humanity and human individuals and this, though maybe not 'fun' is at least affectionate towards other human beings and thus also to interaction.

Comment: You have expressed exactly what I meant. "a lover of humanity" but "maybe not 'fun'". Yes, it covers someone who is "nice and caring", but "fun" is not a given in any definition of the word, or in its standard usage. It would be like saying all doctors are fun. I don't think sources are required.

Comment: I guess I have to give in... ^^ Although I might be picky about the definition of 'fun' ;) You could apply a wide definition as "beneficial for `myself`"

Comment: Fun: *provides amusement or enjoyment*; *violent or excited activity or argument* (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fun) I guess as long as every philanthropist  engages in one or the other, then you might have a case :P